# QIBASE built but not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, firebird

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47457/Get-Started-with-QT-and-Embedded-FireBird) instruction. I used Qt version 4.7.4, firebird 2.1.5, VisualStudio 2010 Pro.

.dlls (`qsqlibase4` and `qsqlite4`) and stuff appear where they should, at `%QtPATH%\plugins\sqldrivers`.

[image]

But when I run my simple test project

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QComboBox myCombo;


    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");
    myCombo.addItems(db.drivers());
    db.setDatabaseName("c:/databases/employee.fdb");
    db.setUserName("SYSDBA");
    db.setPassword("masterkey");

    if(!db.open())
    {
        QSqlError er = db.lastError();
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", er.text());
    }

    myCombo.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I get an error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QIBASE driver not loaded 
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

I am really confused. Drivers are built and it looks like paths are right, but then why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's kinda strange but it helped me! I just made a copy of file `fbclient.dll` from this dir `Firebird_2_1\bin` and just pasted it in dir with my project.exe `win32/Debug`. 
So now `QIBASE` is visible!

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Per default the required DLLs are loaded from the working directory of the executable. And Visual Studio projects usually use "Debug" and "Release" as wokring direcory.